# Add Progress Bar in Every Slide of the Carousel (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

Have a Nice Saturday. I'm gonna ask something about adding progress bar in carousel which the progress bar code reference is in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_3. But after I apply it to my code, it doesn't work at all. It only showed that `cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'width')`. I'm very new in JavaScript, so please Help me to solve this everyone. Here's my snippet :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-item'),
      addActive = function(slide) {slide.classList.add('active-carousel')},
      removeActive = function(slide) {slide.classList.remove('active-carousel')},
      time = 3000,
      a = 0,
      timeLine = function() {if(a == 0) {a = 1; var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-line'), width = 1, id = setInterval(frame,time/100); function frame() {if(width >= 100) {clearInterval(id); a = 0;} else {width++; elem.style.width = width + "%";}}}}; //this one I'm not sure the code is right
      
  addActive(slides[0]);
  
  setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
      if (i + 1 == slides.length) {
        addActive(slides[0]);
        timeLine(slides[0]);
        slides[0].style.zIndex = 3;
        slides[i].classList.add('show-carousel');
        setTimeout(function() {
          slides[i].classList.remove('show-carousel');
        },1000);
        setTimeout(removeActive, 500, slides[i]);
        break;
      }
      
      if (slides[i].classList.contains('active-carousel')) { 
        slides[i].classList.add('show-carousel');
        timeLine(slides[i + 1]);
        setTimeout(function() {
          slides[i].classList.remove('show-carousel');
        },1000);
        slides[i].removeAttribute('style');
        setTimeout(removeActive, 500, slides[i]);
        addActive(slides[i + 1]);
        break;
      }
    } 
  }, time);
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-item {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.progress-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9;
}

.active-carousel {
  display: flex;
  animation-name: slide-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {display: none; bottom: 100%;}
  1% {display: flex; bottom: 100%;}
  100% {display: flex; bottom: 0%;}
}
.show-carousel {
  display: flex;
  animation-name: slide-out;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {display: flex; bottom: 0%;}
  99% {display: flex; bottom: -100%;}
  100% {display: none; bottom: -100%;}
}

div {height: 100%;}
  .red {background-color: red;}
  .green {background-color: green;}
  .yellow {background-color: yellow;}
  .violet {background-color: violet;}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="progress-line">
  </div>
  
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="violet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-item'),
      addActive = function(slide) {slide.classList.add('active-carousel')},
      removeActive = function(slide) {slide.classList.remove('active-carousel')},
      time = 3000,
      a = 0,
      timeLine = function() {if(a == 0) {a = 1; 
      let elem = document.querySelector('.progress-line');
      let width = 1;

      var id = setInterval(frame,time/100); 
      function frame() { if(width >= 100) { clearInterval(id); a = 0;} else {width++; elem.style.width = width + "%";}}}}; 
      
  addActive(slides[0]);
  
  setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
      if (i + 1 == slides.length) {
        addActive(slides[0]);
        timeLine(slides[0]);
        slides[0].style.zIndex = 3;
        slides[i].classList.add('show-carousel');
        setTimeout(function() {
          slides[i].classList.remove('show-carousel');
        },1000);
        setTimeout(removeActive, 500, slides[i]);
        break;
      }
      
      if (slides[i].classList.contains('active-carousel')) { 
        slides[i].classList.add('show-carousel');
        timeLine(slides[i + 1]);
        setTimeout(function() {
          slides[i].classList.remove('show-carousel');
        },1000);
        slides[i].removeAttribute('style');
        setTimeout(removeActive, 500, slides[i]);
        addActive(slides[i + 1]);
        break;
      }
    } 
  }, time);
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-item {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.progress-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 9;
}

.active-carousel {
  display: flex;
  animation-name: slide-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {display: none; bottom: 100%;}
  1% {display: flex; bottom: 100%;}
  100% {display: flex; bottom: 0%;}
}
.show-carousel {
  display: flex;
  animation-name: slide-out;
  animation-duration: 1.1s;
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  0% {display: flex; bottom: 0%;}
  99% {display: flex; bottom: -100%;}
  100% {display: none; bottom: -100%;}
}

div {height: 100%;}
  .red {background-color: red;}
  .green {background-color: green;}
  .yellow {background-color: yellow;}
  .violet {background-color: violet;}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="progress-line">
  </div>
  
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="violet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- `var` not work inside of function use `let`

Comment: Thanks anyway @UttamNath But, why does the progress line not run everytime the slide is changing? Please help, because I'm very new in JavaScript